# Transition effects with Android ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, transition

I have an ImageView, and when it is clicked it has to change image using a transition (e.g. fading, scrolling, ...). How can I do this?

I tried this code

```
imageView.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_wb);
imageView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
```

but it doesn't work with an API < 23 (Android 6.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fadeout.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

fadein.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="6000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

In you java class

```
Animation animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);

Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

    animFadeOut.reset();
    imageview.clearAnimation();
    imageview.startAnimation(animFadeOut);


    animFadeIn.reset();
    imageview.clearAnimation();
    imageview.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
```

and hide or visible imageview where u want

check this also [link](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50#.esd3ra50f)

You need to create a new folder right click on res folder create new folder name it anim. And you can put your animation xmls in it.

Also check this tutorial site its give step by step tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very useful, but which directory do I have to create the *.xml files in?

Comment: Inside res-> anim